# the syntax of from_buffer_copy()

Tags: python, function, syntax, ctypes

I'm reading a book called *Black Hat
Python Python Programming for Hackers and Pentesters*
by Justin Seitz.

This is code from the book:

```
import socket
import os
import struct
from ctypes import *

# host to listen
host = "10.0.2.15"


# our IP header
class IP(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ihl", c_ubyte, 4),
        ("version", c_ubyte,4),
        ("tos", c_ubyte),
        ("len", c_ushort),
        ("id", c_ushort),
        ("offset", c_ubyte),
        ("ttl", c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num", c_ubyte),
        ("sum", c_ubyte),
        ("src", c_ulong),
        ("dst", c_ulong)
    ]
    
    def __new__(cls,socket_buffer=None):
        return cls.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)
```

In this code, inside the function new, there is function called `from_buffer_copy()`. It is a function from the `ctypes` Python library.

I want to know what it does and what is the syntax to use it?

The Python documentation says the syntax is `from_buffer_copy(source[, offset])`.  I have found examples that use this syntax, but the usage definition provided by the documentation is blurry to me.

Python documentation: [from_buffer_copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy)

In this book I saw this function with only one argument, so how is it being implemented?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume it means that offset is optional :)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation `from_buffer_copy(source[, offset])`, square brackets means the 2nd parameter is optional.  In code it is written like the following, where a default value for the optional second parameter is given:

```py
def from_buffer_copy(self, source, offset=0): ...
```

Here's a working example of the difference between `.from_buffer_copy` and `.from_buffer` with explanations.  The functions are used to create Python classes based on memory structures that are received as byte data:

```py
import ctypes as ct

# A simple ctypes structure with two 4-byte fields.
# It will need at least 8 bytes of data to build this structure.
class Demo(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('first', ct.c_uint32),
                ('second', ct.c_uint32))

    # defines the print representation to easily look at the fields
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Demo(first=0x{self.first:08x}. second=0x{self.second:08x})'

# A 10-byte read-only bytes buffer.
# Extra bytes to demonstrate the offset parameter.
buf = bytes([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

try:
    # This syntax constructs a Demo object that refers to the *same*
    # memory that buffer occupies, starting from the default offset of 0,
    # but to do so requires a writeable buffer
    demo1 = Demo.from_buffer(buf)
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)  # This error will print

# This builds the Demo object from a copy of the memory,
# so a read-only buffer can be used, starting from default offset 0.
demo2 = Demo.from_buffer_copy(buf)
print(demo2)

# This builds the object from offset 2, so the values of "first" and
# "second" will be different.
demo3 = Demo.from_buffer_copy(buf,2)
print(demo3)

# This is a writable buffer, so from_buffer will work
buf2 = bytearray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
demo4 = Demo.from_buffer(buf2)
print(demo4)

# Since demo4 references the *same* memory, changing writable buf2
# also changes demo4
buf2[1] = 0xff
print(demo4)
```

Output:

```
underlying buffer is not writable               # error message from demo1 attempt
Demo(first=0x04030201. second=0x08070605)       # demo2 copied from offset 0
Demo(first=0x06050403. second=0x0a090807)       # demo3 copied from offset 2
Demo(first=0x04030201. second=0x08070605)       # demo4
Demo(first=0x0403ff01. second=0x08070605)       # demo4 after write to buf2
```